# Type 'XXX' | undefined is not assignable to type 'XXX' | Undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const textRef = useRef<string>(null);       //ityped function https://www.npmjs.com/package/ityped

useEffect(() => {               //render ityped function
    init(textRef.current!, {
    showCursor: true,
    backDelay: 1500,
    backSpeed:60,
    strings: ["React Assignment by Phuc Le"],
    });
}, []);
return (     
    <span className="ityped" ref={textRef}></span>   //error here
)
```

when I use convert js to ts file, this error:

```
Type 'RefObject<string>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLSpanElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<string>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLSpanElement>'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'HTMLSpanElement'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'
```

happened. Did anyone face this error before and how to fix it?

Comment: The title of your question does not match the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're trying to assign a `HTMLSpanElement` (or in other words the instance of a `<span>` element) to a variable which should contain a `string`.

Change:

`const textRef = useRef<string>(null);`

to:

`const textRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement | null>(null);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer